# Send information or signal from database to the application

Tags: c#, sql-server, triggers

I am developing a C# desktop application using SQL Server 2012.

Suppose that there are two applications.

The first application makes some changes (`INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE,` ...) on a `Persons` table in the database.

How to send a signal or an alert or some from information from database to the second application, that there were some changes in the table?

I can solve it from second application with timer. Check the `Persons` table every 1 or 5 seconds for any changes. But I don't want every time check the database.

Is there any method to send some signals to the application like triggers in the database?

Comment: try http://signalr.net/

Comment: Have a look at [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: Triggers will not work - those "work" in inside the database only

Comment: I have already given an answer. Please refer to the below link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74891087/is-there-a-way-to-notify-backend-server-from-a-postgresql-database-on-some-trigg/75020622#75020622